# integrate node app in angular 2 application

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, node-modules, geoip

i`m working on angular 2 app and i want to convert ip to country locally. so i have some choices such as **geoip-lite** and **geoip-native-lite**.

i have chose geoip-lite for this task. i installed it by npm upon instructions mentioned in `npmjs/geoip-lite` webpage then installed geoip Types for typescript.

but when i add package in my code and use it; i got 404 error that says geoip not found.

is there anybody know what is wrong?

**Typescript code**

[image]

**Error in console**

[image]

Generally what efforts need to do for setup a node app like **geoip-lite** in angular 2?

Comment: better to add code directly in question instead of an image.

Comment: Are you sure geoip-lite can work on the client? It looks like it needs to run in a node app. Not all server-side javascript can run in a webbrowser.

Comment: @Kokodoko thanks. is there anyway for make node apps compatible to run in client side?

Comment: That depends on the npm package, but many of them CAN be used in a webbrowser. Don't forget that you need to bundle all the .js files before deploying! This is because the "require(...)" and  "import .. from" commands don't work natively. You can use browserify or webpack to compile (node) modules into a single .js file. Check http://browserify.org